# How to use edge abilities in practice with Jaseci?

Tags: jaseci

In a jac code, I want to use an edge ability. Let's imagine we have the following graph;

[image]

I have defined the edge ability as follows;

```
edge road{
    has distance;
    has count;

    can count_travelers with traveler entry{
        count = ++count;
        std.out("travels");
    }
}
```

I want to increase `count` when `walker traveler` travers through the `edge road`. This is my `walker init`

```
walker init{
    root{
        spawn here walker::build_example;
        take-->;
    }
    city{
        spawn here walker::traveler;
        take-->;
    }
}
```

The the code executes flawlessly but `count` does not increase. What am I missing here?

> In the bible it was mentioned that edge can have abilities, but couldn't find any example in bible or in any codelabs in jaseci github repository.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Jaseci, edge abilities only execute when explicitly called. If `with entry` or `with exit` is applied to an edge ability its basically ignored. You can call it with something like `-->.edge[0]::count_travelers` though.